# R - shuffle a list preserving element sizes

Tags: r, list

In R, I need an efficient solution to shuffle the elements contained within a list, preserving the total number of elements, and the local element sizes (in this case, each element of the list is a vector)

```
a<-LETTERS[1:6]
b<-LETTERS[6:10]
c<-LETTERS[c(9:15)]

l=list(a,b,c)
> l
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"

[[2]]
[1] "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"

[[3]]
[1] "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O"
```

The shuffling should randomly select the letters of the list (without replacement) and put them in a random position of any vector within the list.

I hope I have been clear! Thanks :-)

Comment: Do you just want the elements in each vector to be shuffled within the vector?  Or do you want the same structure of the list but all of the elements (combined) to be shuffled?  So if 'a' is an element of the first vector should 'a' necessarily be in the first vector after the shuffle or could it end up in the second vector?

Comment: Hi Dason, the elements should be shuffled across the whole list, i.e. a letter in the first vector can end up in any other vector

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you may try recreating a second list with the skeleton of the first, and fill it with all the elements of the first list, like this:

```
u<-unlist(l)
l2<-relist(u[sample(length(u))],skeleton=l)
> l2
[[1]]
[1] "F" "A" "O" "I" "S" "Q"

[[2]]
[1] "R" "P" "K" "F" "G"

[[3]]
 [1] "A" "N" "M" "J" "H" "G" "E" "B" "T" "C" "D" "L"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I always forget about `relist`.  Nice answer.

Comment: Personally I like the version pre-edit more.  It gives the correct answer in the case of `l <- list(5)` whereas the new version doesn't.

Comment: I agree, can you put it back as it was?

Comment: Yep, sorry, I betrayed functionality for tidiness. A mistake I have corrected now.

Answer (score 3):

Like this...?

```
> set.seed(1)
> lapply(l, sample)
[[1]]
[1] "B" "F" "C" "D" "A" "E"

[[2]]
[1] "J" "H" "G" "F" "I"

[[3]]
[1] "J" "M" "O" "L" "N" "K" "I"
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it will shuffle the letters only within the vectors. Sorry for being not clear about what I wanted :-(

Comment: Apparently this isn't what they want - but that doesn't bug me.  The tricky part here is that *if* the list contains integers and you end up with a vector of length 1 the result won't quite be the same since sample(5) actually is the same as sample(1:5) which can be convenient sometimes but personally I think it's not necessarily a good thing...

Comment: I didnt fully understand the OP's question :(

Comment: It's alright - I didn't either when it was first asked which is why I made the comment.  They edited the question to make it more clear now though but Federico already as a nice answer.